# iOS odd Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Getting a

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

error when running an app on iPad - it works on iPhones.

In a `UITableView` in a `Master-Detail` app, I've got the `numberOfRowsInSection` returning the count on an array, and apparently it's not getting initialized before the call. Here is the relevant code:

```
var myObjects = [[MyObject]]()
var first =  [MyObject]()
var second = [MyObject]()

let sectionTitles = ["First", "Second"]

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    ...
    loadMyObjects()
    ...
}


private func loadAmenities() {

    myObjects.removeAll()
    guard let myObject1 = new MyObject(name: "One", property2: "initialized_property") else {
    fatalError("Failed to initialize myObject1")
    }

    ...

    first += [myObject1, myObject2, myObject3, myObject4]
    second += [myObject5, myObject6, myObject7]
    myObjects = [first, second]
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionTitles.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)-> Int {
    return myObjects[section].count // error happens here
}
```

Where should I be instantiating the data before the table tries to load? This is weird in that it is the tableView causing the issue, but the tableView loads properly in iPhone. Thanks for any help.

Edit:

On iPhone, it appears that the `viewWillAppear` method gets called before the tableview's `numberOfRowsInSection`, but in iPad, it's the opposite order. In fact, the `viewDidLoad` and `tableView` methods are called before `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Please copy and paste real code. And is there any async processing going on?

Comment: There are no async processes, and the code is the same whether it's abstracted or not.

Comment: Well something in your guard statement could be causing the issue by not initialising all the objects correctly but without the actual code it's impossible to say.  As @rmaddy said post actual code not the cut down version.

Comment: If it were a guard issue, then there would be a failure on that line, and all of the objects are loaded in iPhone properly.

Comment: You could slap a breakpoint on the line that's crashing, then observe the call stack to see who is calling reloadData? Can't tell much else without more code.

Comment: No necessarily if the guard statement doesn't initialise all the 'myObject' items then myObjects will remain empty.  Then when the guard statement exits out (which it must but you haven't posted it all) the sectionTitles.count will be two but myObjects will still be empty thus causing a crash on the line indicated.  Without seeing more code it's impossible to say for certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `viewWillLoad` method was not being called in iPad, and since the initializations of the data arrays are all local data and there's no need for asynchronous loading, the easiest workaround was to test an array and call the loading function in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    if winter.count < 1 {
        loadAmenities()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfSections` needs to return `myObjects.count`.  The tableview is requesting data before you have loaded data into the `myObjects` array, but `sectionTitles` is initialised when the VC is instantiated.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myObjects.count
}
```

You will also need to reload the table once you have added the data.

The reason the crash only occurs on iPad is due to the different behaviour of the master-detail controller on an iPad.

Comment: Thanks for having a look - there's definitely somethin happening with the failure to initialize before the view loads on iPad.

The myObjects variable is an array of myObject arrays - so I actually need the count `myObject[section].count` - which is fine on iPad. The whole rubbish started because I tried to organize the table with headers, myObjects.count was what I had before needing to convert it to a multidimensional array

Comment: You should always return the count of the section data array in `numberOfSections`. Returning the section header count is wrong

Comment: I'm not returning the header count. I'm returning the count of the array - first or second - in the myObjects array. Which one is based on the method's section argument.

Comment: No, but in `numberOfSections` you are returning the count of your section headers. You should always return the count of your section data source, which in this case is `myObjects`